# Can I attach an image to a different post?

Tags: gallery, images, media-library

Image galleries display those images that were uploaded to that post, by default. If I wanted to move an image to a different post, so it appeared there instead, would I have to delete and re-upload? Or, is there a way to re-assign an image that's already in the Media Library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/detach-amp-re-attach-media-attachment-images-from-posts#post-1609173

I've saved this as a snippet in my IDE for use in projects. Very handy!

Comment: NICE, man! I'll try this!

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in a Gallery you would need to delete it, or exclude it inside the short-code for the gallery.

If it's a single image you could just delete it from that page (not from the media manager). It could be used inside a different page by uploading it.

I'm not aware of a simple way to remove single images from galleries (without excluding it with short-code). I tried the link that posted by:Brian Fegter. It did add a re-attach button but I don't see how that is relevant to this specific question.

Comment: It's relevant to the question in that it reassigns the post_parent column and therefore removes it from the gallery functionality of the original post. The gallery grabs the child attachments of that specific post (via post_parent). If that image's post_parent has changed, Wordpress does not include it in the original post gallery.

Comment: I didn't try that. If it works I apologize and I'll return to +1 your answer. I've been cursing the default gallery for the lack of control over gallery images.

Comment: No worries Jared. There are major changes coming to the media management in a future release. I too share your frustrations. One such frustration is if a post thumbnail is set, why does it get placed in the gallery? If a theme displays the thumb, it's displayed a second time in the gallery. Arg :)

Comment: I stand corrected. It does work. It would be nice to have a way to remove an image directly from the gallery panel, but this will do until or if that happens. Thanks for the tip!