# How do I detach images from posts?

Tags: posts, images, attachments, media

Firstly I've seen some topics like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31833/how-can-i-un-attach-media-from-a-post), but they haven't helped me.

---

I've attached some images to a post via "Add Media" :

[image]

And for showing these attached images, I used following code in `single.php` file :

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();           
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );      
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
            echo '<p>';
            echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
            echo '</p></li>';
        }
    }       
endwhile; endif;
```

This shows the attached images and works fine.

**The Problem :**

When I remove an attached image from a post:

[image]

The removed image still exists in that post!

How can I completely detach images from posts?

P.S. I also tried `Ctrl + F5`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you view the Media Library in the *list* mode:

```
/wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list
```

then you will see the *Attach*/*Detach* links for each attachment.

Each attachment can only be attached to a single parent through the `post_parent` field in the `wp_posst` table.

Deleting an image from the post editor will not change the `post_parent` field to 0.

### Making life a little bit easier!

It would be nice to be able to do it within the *Media View* popup, when editing a post, since it can take a long time to find it within the media library.

[image: Custom link]

First we construct a custom Backbone micro template, that we will add to the *Attachment Details* view:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wpse-open-in-library">
    <div class="wpse-open-in-library">
        <a href="<?php echo admin_url('upload.php?mode=list&p=');?>{{ data.id }}" target="_blank">
             <?php _e( 'Open in Media Library' ); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</script>
```

where `{{ data.id }}` is the current attachment's ID.

This is how we insert it after the *Delete Attachment* link:

```
$( wp.media.template('wpse-open-in-library')(
      { 
         id: attachment.get( 'id' )  // <-- This is how we can fetch the current ID 
      }
    ) 
 ).insertAfter('.delete-attachment');
```

where we pass the `id` variable to our custom micro template.

Note that we can view all the attached files by selecting the following option:

[image: attached files]

### Demo plugin

Here's the whole demo plugin:

```
/**
 * Open an attachment in the Media Library, to be able to attach/detach it
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/206179/26350
 */
add_action( 'print_media_templates', function()
{ ?>

  <!-- Custom template part -->
  <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wpse-open-in-library">
        <div class="wpse-open-in-library">
            <a href="<?php echo admin_url('upload.php?mode=list&p=');?>{{ data.id }}" target="_blank">
                <?php _e( 'Open in Media Library' ); ?>
           </a>
       </div>
  </script>

  <!-- Extend the Attachment Details View -->
  <script>
      jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) 
      {
          wp.media.view.Settings.AttachmentDisplay = wp.media.view.Settings.AttachmentDisplay.extend(
          {
              render: function() 
              {
                  wp.media.View.prototype.render.apply( this, arguments );
                  var attachment = this.options.attachment;
                  $( wp.media.template('wpse-open-in-library')(
                        { 
                            id: attachment.get( 'id' ) 
                        }
                     ) 
                  ).insertAfter('.delete-attachment');

                return this;
            }
      } );
    } );
  </script>
<?php
} );
```

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194716/adding-fields-to-the-media-uploader-with-jquery-listeners) by @kalimah-apps  and the [answers here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142997/delete-an-attachment-in-the-wp-media-modal-window) by @bonger and @Fabien Quatravaux, were of great help construction this demo plugin.

Then the next step would be to add the *Detach* link, to make it even easier ;-)

Comment: I wish I could give you +1000 up-votes. Thanks...

Comment: What changes should I make if I want to each image have multiple parents?

Comment: You're welcome, hopefully you can adjust it to your needs. The single parent is hard-coded into the `wp_posts` table, so to speak, but I haven't looked into a possible workaround. Maybe it has already been solved here on [wordpress.se] ? If not, then that might be better served as a new question. @HamedKamrava